# Problem to ignore null values and members when use mapster in my blazor project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor, mapster

I have 2 objects. the first one is my dto model and the second one is my real entity.
Of course, my dto model does not have all properties of my entity. So when i use **Adapt** method to transfer values from my dto to entity, the rest of properties which does not exists in my dto model sets to null!

I've googled alot and found some tips to ignore null values or ignore Members, but nothing worked!!

Here is my sample code :

```
var config = new TypeAdapterConfig();
config.NewConfig<RelationDTO, CRM_CustomerRelation>()
    .IgnoreNullValues(true);
config.ForType<RelationDTO, CRM_CustomerRelation>()
    .IgnoreMember((member, side) => member.Name == "SortID"
        || member.Name == "CreatedBy"
        || member.Name == "DateCreated"
        || member.Name == "TimeCreated");
CRM_CustomerRelation relation;
if(isNewMode)
{
    // ...
}
else
{
    // ... Get  relation from database
     relation = relationDto.Adapt<CRM_CustomerRelation>(config); // after call this method, all above members sets to null!
}
```

Where is my problem and how to solve it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: " i use Adapt method to transfer values from my dto to entity" Usually  we map the values from the entities , transfer values from  entity to dto. What's your model class of the  entity and dto ? What the value do you set for the entity ? How do you define the  relationDto ?

Comment: Hi again, Sorry for late reply. I'm also using mapster to transfer my entity values to my dto and vice versa. The problem is that my dto object does not have all entity values and when i use adapt to transfer values from dto to entity, some other entity properties which does not exists in dto object sets to null and when i update database via entity sets null values on database too!!!